What is the best/suggested way in C# to get an instance of ILogger<TCategoryName> for those classes which are not registered by the DI framework
Let say I have a class called Person and defined like below
public class Person
{
    public Person(string name, int age);
    ...
}

This is not a service class registered (by calling AddSingleton, etc.) in the DI framework.
If I want to have a logger ILogger<Person> for this Person class, what can I do?
Approach 1. Create the logger directly within the class
public class Person
{
    private ILogger<Person> logger =
        LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder
            .AddConsole()
            .SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information)
            .AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning)
            ...
        );

    public Person(string name, int age);
    ...
}

But the problem is that I need to create the logger for every class and configure it (AddConsole, SetMinimumLevel, etc.). And it looks like that the logger level of this logger cannot be controlled by the appsettings.json.
Approach 2. Pass in from the outer service registered in the DI framework.
Although I want to have something like below.
public class SchoolService: ISchoolService
{
    // logger to log message within class SchoolService
    private ILogger<SchoolService> _logger;
    // logger to log message within class Person
    private ILogger<Person> _personLogger;

    public SchoolService(ILogger<SchoolService> logger, ILogger<Person> personLogger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _personLogger = personLogger;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Creating student");
        Person student = new Person("Ben", 15, _personLogger);
        ...
    }
}

It looks good, but there is still problem. It means I need to pass all the different loggers from the top level service to the final class, imagine if I have more than 10 classes called by SchoolService in a hierarchy and each class needs to hold logger of another class if it wants to use instance of that class. Also, writing to console/file is somehow by default in most of the cases. I do not really want to add constructor or method to inject the logger in such a way.
Hence, the question is:
Is there a more elegant way to create the logger (for those classes which are not registered by the DI framework) without such complication?
Any help is highly appreciated.

All those system work well when you have a clear distinction between classes doing logic (often called services like your SchoolService) and having classes that represent data flowing through services. And a class called Person sound definetly like the data category. So the answer to your question is that such a class should not have dependencies like on ILogger as it should not do logic that can fail and may need logging. IF Person somehow contains logic that feels like a problem and you should look at that to keep Person dependency free.

So the answer to your question is to choose approach 3 "don't need ILogger".

If I want to have a logger ILogger<Person> why do you want that in the first place? That's where the problem starts. The category is what the name says, a category, not a file name. You can use the service name to categorize logs for a specific service or module together, to make it easier for you to understand what's going an and search the logs when something goes wrong. Creating 1 category for every type in your project just adds noise to logs

Instead of creating a new logger for every type, you can create log scopes and add extra information. You can create one log scope per request for example, that includes data like the user, product, etc. This would allow you to easily find all logs created for a specific operation

Also reconsider what to log. What benefit does a log output of _logger.LogInformation("Creating student"); have? So it says it created a student at timestamp xyz. "Great" ...

As suggested by others, your domain models should be free from unwanted responsibilities and convey everything with results or side effects. For example, an exception thrown at the domain, and logged at service level is enough to log information with context about domain. Excessive logging should also be avoided just like how logging too less is avoided. Domain typically tend to fail less on its own.

Got the point that the service class and the data object have different responsibilities and normally speaking, there should be no much complication in the data object thus no logging is required. The example I showed is just a simplified one to show what I want to achieve. The actual case is much more complicated as something are legacy and out of my control. Some modules are there by others more than 10 years ago before the DI framework is introduced. Also, there is no much concept about separation of domain objects and the business logic.

In my case, for example, a student/person object can call BuySomething() method to call another external service. As I do not have access on the external service easily, I would like to log the final request (which is dynamically constructed in Person class) we send (the reason why I need a logger here). I know it is a bad design, but it is what it is long time ago. Refactoring it is possible, but need too much time.

We can't answer the question if refactoring or bending the system is better here. Thats your decision just remember everytime you go for bending the next refactoring will get even harder.

Then you should go for something like approach 2. Think about creating a factory for that (here a PersonFactory) that can be created by DI and injected to hide al the ugly "how to get all the dependencies in the class" code. approach 1 might get you into problem if you use certain loggers and certain logging sinks. Logging to Console might work more or less always. But the concrete Logger implementation might get into sharing/locking problems when say logging to a file.
